# What is the correct way to set up S3 for loading content in the browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to do the following: a user in a browser types some text and after he presses a 'Save' button, the text should be saved in a file (for example: content.txt) in a folder (for example: /username_text) on the root of an S3 bucket.

Also, I want the user to be able, when he visits the same page, load the content from S3 and continue working on the file. Then, if he/she is done, save the file to S3 again.

Probably important to mention, but I plan on using NodeJS for my back-end...

My question now is: What is the best way to set this storing-and-retrieving thing up? Do I create an API gateway + Lambda function to GET and POST files through that? Or do I for example use the aws-sdk in Node to directly push and pull files from S3? Or is there a better way to do this?

I looked at the following two guides:

1. [Using AWS S3 Buckets in a NodeJS App – Codebase – Medium](https://medium.com/codebase/using-aws-s3-buckets-in-a-nodejs-app-74da2fc547a6)
2. [Image Upload and Retrieval from S3 Using AWS API Gateway and Lambda](https://medium.com/think-serverless/image-upload-and-retrieval-from-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-b4c2961e8d1)

Comment: I have edited my answer to cover your question whether you should do it via API GW vs Browser. Had missed it on my original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I think you are worrying too much about the not-so-important stuff. S3 is nothing but a storage system. You could have decided to store the content of these files on DynamoDB, RDS, etc. What would you do if you stored its contents on these real databases? You'd fetch for data and display it to the user, wouldn't you?

This is what you need to do with S3! S3 is a smart choice on your scenario because your "file" can grow very big and S3 is a great place for storing files. However, apparently, you're not actually storing files (think of .pdf, .mp4, .mov, etc.), you're essentially only storing human-readable text.

So here's one approach on how to solve your problem:

**FETCHING FILE CONTENT**

1. User logs in
2. You fetch the user's personal information based on some token. You can store all the metadata in DynamoDB, where given a user_id, fetch all the "files" from this user. These "files" (metadata only) would be the bucket and key for the actual file on S3.
3. You use the `getObject` API from S3 to fetch the file based on your query and display the body of your file to your user in a RESTful way. Your response should look something like this:

   {
       "content": "some content"
   }

**SAVING FILE CONTENT**

1. User logs in
2. The user writes anything in a form and submits it. In your Lambda function, you grab the content of this form and process it. This request should look something like this:

   {
       "file_id": "some-id",
       "user_id": "some-id",
       "content": "some-content"
   }
3. If the file_id exists, update the content in S3. Otherwise, upload a new file in S3 and then create a new entry in DynamoDB. You'd then, of course, have to handle if the user submitting the changes actually owns the file, but if you're using UUIDs it shouldn't be too much of a problem, but still worth checking in case an ID is leaked somehow.

This way, you don't need to worry about uploading/downloading files as these are CPU intensive tasks, so you can keep your costs low as well as using very little RAM in your functions (128MB should be more than enough), after all, you're now only serving text. Not only this will simplify your way of designing it, but will also make things simpler both in API Gateway and in your code as you won't have to deal with binary types. The maximum you'll do is convert the buffer from S3 to a String when serving some content, but this should be completely fine.

**EDIT**

On your question regarding whether you should upload it from the browser or not, I suggest you take a look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292696/how-do-i-call-a-netlify-lambda-function-from-my-react-app/55294061#55294061) where I cover the pros/cons of doing it via API Gateway vs from the Browser.

Comment: Wow! First question on the platform and such an extensive answer! Truly: thanks a million. You are right that I worry too much about the non-important stuff about S3 and that it should primarily be used for storing non-human readable files (aka images/videos). Thanks for this clarification as well!

Comment: I am happy you've had a positive experience with you first question and answer :)

Comment: S3 is a great choice for your use case. I only said you were caring too much about the not-so-important stuff because you were thinking "files" rather than thinking "text". Since your users' input can be large amounts of text, storing it in S3 is the right way to go.